# How to grab the java versions/spark versions/ pip list and anaconda list from multiple servers using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, sh

This is my first post on this stackoverflow site.
I'm trying to grab the java versions/spark versions/ pip list and anaconda list from multiple servers using bash script.
In which I have already tried few attempts but it doen't help much..
Please take a look and help me in this..

```
set -x
#!/bin/bash -x
user=`whoami` #checks which user logged in

if [ "$user" != "spark" ]; then
  echo "You must be spark to run this script"
  exit 1
fi

id=$1
if [ $# = 2 ]; then
  ENV=$2
else
  ENV=IQA
fi
if [ "$ENV" == "IQA" ]; then
  HOST="19.928.282.26 19.928.282.27 19.928.282.20 19.928.282.31"
elif [ "$ENV" == "DEV" ]; then
  HOST="19.928.282.226 19.928.282.27 319.928.282.250 19.928.522.232"
elif [ "$ENV" == "STAGE" ]; then
  HOST="19.928.282.286 19.928.282.24 319.928.282.255 19.928.522.233"
elif [ "$ENV" == "PERF" ]; then
  HOST="19.928.282.225 19.928.282.25 319.928.282.260 19.928.522.236"
elif [ "$ENV" == "PRODNA" ]; then
  HOST="19.928.282.26 19.928.285.27 56.928.282.45 19.928.522.90"
elif [ "$ENV" == "PRODEU" ]; then
  HOST="19.928.282.276 19.928.282.56 319.928.282.254 19.928.522.245"
else
  echo "You must specify a valid environment... IQA, DEV, STAGE, PERF, PRODN or PRODEU"
  exit 1
fi

mkdir -p "/tmp/kumar/${HOSTNAME}_Java_Version_Details"

if [[ $id == javaversion* ]]; then
  echo "Grabbing the details of $id"
for HOSTS in ${HOST}; do
ssh ${user}@${HOSTS} "java -version 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep \"java version\" | awk \"{print $3}\"" > /tmp/kumar/${HOSTNAME}_Java_Version_Details/${HOSTS}_java_list.txt
 done
exit 0
fi
done
exit 1


elif [[ $id == sparkversion* ]]; then
  echo "Grabbing the details of $id"
  for HOSTS in ${HOST}; do
ssh ${user}@${HOSTS} "spark-submit --version  > /tmp/${HOSTNAME}_spark_versionlist.txt  2>&1" > /tmp/kumar/${HOSTNAME}_spark_versionlist.txt
 done
exit 0
fi
done
exit 1
elif [[ $id == condalist* ]]; then
  echo "Grabbing the details of $id"
  for HOSTS in ${HOST}; do
ssh ${user}@${HOSTS} "/opt/anaconda/bin/conda list > /tmp/${HOSTNAME}_conda_list.txt" > /tmp/kumar/${HOSTNAME}_conda_list.txt
 done
exit 0
fi
done
exit 1
elif [[ $id == piplist* ]]; then
  echo "Grabbing the details of $id"
  for HOSTS in ${HOST}; do
ssh ${user}@${HOSTS} "/opt/anaconda/bin/pip list > /tmp/${HOSTNAME}_pip_list.txt 2> /dev/null" > /tmp/kumar/${HOSTNAME}_pip_list.txt
 done
exit 0
fi
done
exit 1
```

I'm trying to make the above script to grab the details from all the nodes of the selected environment and stors it in the masternode (ie.node01) of that environment..
But when i execute the above script it doesnt generate the files from node 01-10 instead it just creates only on node01..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected the errors and now the code is ready to run..
The below code will do:

## Step 1: checks the user is spark or not

## step 2: gets the inputs from the user(example: ./script2.sh javaversion IQA)

## step 3: checks the output directory is exist or not(example: /tmp/kumar/javaversion)

## step 4: Execute the command and store the result at the output directory(example: /tmp/kumar/javaversion/45.468.788.67_java_list.txt

## step 5: zip the output directory (example: /tmp/kumar/javaversion.zip)

## step 6: Delete the directory (example: /tmp/kumar/javaversion/)

#!/bin/bash

```
user=`whoami` #checks which user logged in
if [ "$user" != "spark" ]
then
    echo "You must be spark to run this script"
    #exit 1
fi

id=$1
if [ $# = 2 ]
then
    ENV=$2
else
    ENV=IQA
fi

case $ENV in
    'IQA')
    HOSTS="19.928.282.26 19.928.282.27 19.928.282.20 19.928.282.31"
    ;;
'DEV')
    HOSTS="19.928.282.226 19.928.282.27 319.928.282.250 19.928.522.232"
    ;;
'STAGE')
    HOSTS="19.928.282.286 19.928.282.24 319.928.282.255 19.928.522.233"
    ;;
'PERF')
    HOSTS="19.928.282.225 19.928.282.25 319.928.282.260 19.928.522.236"
    ;;
'PRODNA')
    HOSTS="19.928.282.26 19.928.285.27 56.928.282.45 19.928.522.90"
    ;;
'PRODEU')
    HOSTS="19.928.282.276 19.928.282.56 319.928.282.254 19.928.522.245"
    ;;
*)
        echo "You must specify a valid environment... IQA, DEV, STAGE, PERF, PRODN or PRODEU"
        exit 1
esac
output_dir="/tmp/${id}"

if [ ! -d ${output_dir} ]
then
    mkdir -p ${output_dir}
fi


case $id in
    'javaversion')
        echo "Grabbing the details of $id"
        for HOST in ${HOSTS}
        do
            echo "Java version of $HOST": > $output_dir/${HOST}_java_list.txt
                  ssh ${user}@${HOST} "java -version 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep \"java version\" | awk \"{print $3}\"" >> $output_dir/${HOST}_java_list.txt
                  zip -r ${id}.zip ${output_dir}
                  done
        ;;
    'sparkversion')
        echo "Grabbing the details of $id"
        for HOST in ${HOSTS}
        do
         ssh ${user}@${HOST} "spark-submit --version"  > $output_dir/${HOST}_sparkversion.txt  2>&1
         zip -r ${id}.zip ${output_dir}
        done
        ;;
    'condalist')
        echo "Grabbing the details of $id"
        for HOST in ${HOSTS}
        do
            echo "Anaconda version for $HOST:" > $output_dir/${HOST}_conda_list.txt
            ssh ${user}@${HOST} "/opt/anaconda/bin/conda list" >> $output_dir/${HOST}_conda_list.txt
            zip -r ${id}.zip ${output_dir}
            ls -latr $output_dir/${HOST}_conda_list.txt
        done

        ;;
    'piplist')
        echo "Grabbing the details of $id"
        for HOST in ${HOSTS}
        do
            echo "PIP information for $HOST:" > $output_dir/${HOST}_pip_list.txt
            ssh ${user}@${HOST} "/opt/anaconda/bin/pip list 2> /dev/null" >> $output_dir/${HOST}_pip_list.txt
             zip -r ${id}.zip ${output_dir}
        done
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Invalid value for id.  Valid values are javaversion, sparkversion, condalist, piplist"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
if [ ! -z ${output_dir} ]
then
if [ -d ${output_dir} ]
then
rm -rf ${output_dir}
  fi
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

I took a deeper look at your script and decided to tackle the issues.

- I replaced the `if then elif else fi` with `case` statements.
- I reversed the name of the $HOST and $HOSTS variable.  For me $HOSTS is the list of hosts, $HOST is 1 single host in a for loop.  Makes more sense to my brain :)
- I obviously could not try the ssh statements, I just reworked the structure around them.
- Remove the first line (`set -x`).  Not required if you use `#!/bin/bash -x` anyway.
- Doing with `case` now provides validation of the value of $id and $ENV.
- Fixed some confusion between $HOSTNAME and $HOST.  I am not convinced you want the ${HOSTNAME}_Java_Version_Details directory but I left it there.
- Your code had syntax errors.
- Use `>` and `>>` carefully.  `>` overwrites the file with the new content, so you loose what was already in there.

Obviously this can be reworked to structure the output files like you need them.  So finally here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

user=`whoami` #checks which user logged in
if [ "$user" != "spark" ]
then
    echo "You must be spark to run this script"
    #exit 1
fi

id=$1
if [ $# = 2 ]
then
    ENV=$2
else
    ENV=IQA
fi

case $ENV in
    'IQA')
        HOSTS="19.928.282.26 19.928.282.27 19.928.282.20 19.928.282.31"
        ;;
    'DEV')
        HOSTS="19.928.282.226 19.928.282.27 319.928.282.250 19.928.522.232"
        ;;
    'STAGE')
        HOSTS="19.928.282.286 19.928.282.24 319.928.282.255 19.928.522.233"
        ;;
    'PERF')
        HOSTS="19.928.282.225 19.928.282.25 319.928.282.260 19.928.522.236"
        ;;
    'PRODNA')
        HOSTS="19.928.282.26 19.928.285.27 56.928.282.45 19.928.522.90"
        ;;
    'PRODEU')
        HOSTS="19.928.282.276 19.928.282.56 319.928.282.254 19.928.522.245"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "You must specify a valid environment... IQA, DEV, STAGE, PERF, PRODN or PRODEU"
        exit 1
esac

# DEBUG echo "$id, $ENV"

output_dir="/tmp/kumar"
output_dir_javaversion="$output_dir/${HOSTNAME}_Java_Version_Details"
if [ ! -d $output_dir_javaversion ]
then
    mkdir -p "/tmp/kumar/${HOSTNAME}_Java_Version_Details"
fi

case $id in
    'javaversion')
        echo "Grabbing the details of $id"
        for HOST in ${HOSTS}
        do
            echo "Java version of $HOST": > $output_dir_javaversion/${HOST}_java_list.txt
            ssh ${user}@${HOST} "java -version 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep \"java version\" | awk \"{print $3}\"" >> $output_dir_javaversion/${HOST}_java_list.txt
        done
        ;;
    'sparkversion')
        echo "Grabbing the details of $id"
        for HOST in ${HOSTS}
        do
            echo "Spark version for $HOST:" > $output_dir/${HOST}_spark_versionlist.txt
            ssh ${user}@${HOST} "spark-submit --version  > /tmp/${HOSTNAME}_spark_versionlist.txt  2>&1" >> $output_dir/${HOST}_spark_versionlist.txt
        done
        ;;
    'condalist')
        echo "Grabbing the details of $id"
        for HOST in ${HOSTS}
        do
            echo "Anaconda version for $HOST:" > $output_dir/${HOST}_conda_list.txt
            ssh ${user}@${HOSTS} "/opt/anaconda/bin/conda list > /tmp/${HOSTNAME}_conda_list.txt" >> $output_dir/${HOST}_conda_list.txt
        done
        ;;
    'piplist')
        echo "Grabbing the details of $id"
        for HOST in ${HOSTS}
        do
            echo "PIP information for $HOST:" > $output_dir/${HOST}_pip_list.txt
            ssh ${user}@${HOSTS} "/opt/anaconda/bin/pip list > /tmp/${HOSTNAME}_pip_list.txt 2> /dev/null" >> $output_dir/${HOST}_pip_list.txt
        done
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Invalid value for id.  Valid values are javaversion, sparkversion, condalist, piplist"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Actually am trying to grab the output files from all the nodes into masternode (ie.node01)in corresponding folder.

Comment: Say example:
If i chose the option to run spark version then the script needs to get the spark versions from all the nodes in the form of .txt file and place it on master node (location /tmp/kumar/spark_version_Details/${HOSTNAME}_Spark_Version_list.txt..
so once the script ran successfully i can use winscp to download all the files into my local machine..

Comment: we need the script to create the output folder on each node in the corresponding host name say example host1_javalist.txt, host2_javalist.txt host3_javalist.txt and so on..then on the masternode the folder should contains of all the collective outputs from node01-10 with the corresponding hostnames

Comment: actually the spark command works but it just creating the output file on each node as:
[spark@qwyl02 tmp]$ ls -latr qwylbtidlspk01_spark_versionlist.txt
-rw-------. 1 spark spark 281 Mar 22 07:48 qwylbtidlspk01_spark_versionlist.txt
[spark@qwyl02 tmp]$ cat /tmp/qwyl01_spark_versionlist.txt
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.0.1
      /_/
Type --help for more information.

Comment: This is where you start working, and I am done.  The script gives you quite enough to start, then you customize it for the specific output you want.  Have fun!

Comment: Thank you so much Nic3500.. Really appreciate your timely help..
And I am done..the code is now ready to run..